# Select freezes loading a lot of data with JQuery .html() and JSON

Tags: jquery, json

My code:

```
$.getJSON("registro/backend.php?action=list&id="+sel.value, function(data){

            var options = [];

            for (var i=0; i<data.rows.length; i++) {
                options += '<option value="' + data.rows[i].id + '">' + data.rows[i].name + '</option>';
            }
            $("#select").html(options);
        })
```

This code freezes the select and the navigator when the data to load is too big (a lot of data encoded in JSON).

Is there any way to load in the background or improve the performance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should store the length of your array in your loop, and sotre your variable to reduce access to array.

```
for (var i=0,len=data.rows.length; i<len; i++) {
var row = data.rows[i];
options += '<option value="' + row.id + '">' + row.name + '</option>';
            }
```

Reference : http://browserdiet.com/#use-for-instead-of-each

Answer (score 0):

Try to use $.each function ...

```
$.getJSON("registro/backend.php?action=list&id="+sel.value, function(response){

                var options = [];

                $.each(response,function(index,data){
                    options += '<option value="' + data.rows[index].id + '">' + data.rows[index].name + '</option>';
                }
                }
                $("#select").html(options);
            })
```

Comment: Not sure this will be more performant, check the link in ref of my answer.

Comment: Most of the time i use each and it works nicely for me but thanx for the link!